# How do I change the file name of a path without changing its directory or extension?

Tags: rust, path

What's the best way to implement the `change_file_name` function?

```rust
let path = Path::new("/path/to/file.rs");
let new_path = change_file_name(&path, "new_file_name") // -> "/path/to/new_file_name.rs"
```

Comment: The most _easiest_ is probably to create your own trait and extend `Path`/`PathBuf` and use [`set_file_name()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/path/struct.PathBuf.html#method.set_file_name)/[`with_file_name()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/path/struct.Path.html#method.with_file_name). Though you'd need to add logic for retaining the extension of course

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take something that can be referenced as a `Path`, then pop off the existing filename, replacing it and preserving the optional extension:

```
use std::path::{Path, PathBuf};

fn change_file_name(path: impl AsRef<Path>, name: &str) -> PathBuf {
    let path = path.as_ref();
    let mut result = path.to_owned();
    result.set_file_name(name);
    if let Some(ext) = path.extension() {
        result.set_extension(ext);
    }
    result
}

fn main() {
    let path = "/path/to/file.rs";
    let new_path = change_file_name(path, "new_file_name");
    assert_eq!(new_path, Path::new("/path/to/new_file_name.rs"));
}
```

See also:

- [How to get only the directory portion of the current executable's path?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46749360/155423)
- [Replacing Path parts in Rust](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44419890/155423)
- [Best way to format a file name based on another path in Rust](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43019846/155423)
- [Extracting a file extension from a given path in Rust idiomatically](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45291832/155423)
- [How do I replace the file extension of a PathBuf or Path?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59204100/155423)